# Is there something like "make localmodconfig" that detects *all* your hardware?

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling

I understand that Linux's "localmodconfig" target looks through all your loaded kernel modules and produces a .config file that enables those modules.  This is nice, but what about hardware whose support is compiled into my running kernel ("=y" rather than "=m" in Kconfig parlance)?  Is there something like "make localmodconfig", but broader, that will detect *all* my hardware (looking, I suppose, under /sys/bus and /sys/devices etc)?